# width mismatch in output variable declaration VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I am creating a 10 bit register with the below code.The code should clear the register when clr = '1', and load the data on a clock tick when ld='1'.

When I run the following code, I get an error for the assignment of q, 
"width mismatch in assignment; target has 10 bits, source has 20 bits."

```
    process(clk, clr, d, q)
    begin
       if clr = '1' then
           q <= '0';
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
           if ld = '1' then
              q <= d;
           end if;
        end if;
    end process;
```

Comment: Please include the declarations of `q` and `d`; but I guess that `q` is 10 bits long, and `d` is 20 bits long, so that explains the error ;-)  Btw. `q` and `d` are not needed in the process sensitivity list, since events on these values does cause changes in the output; only events on `clk` and `clr` does.

Comment: The error tells you exactly what's wrong. Did you have a question?

Comment: Your error appears to be from Vivado ([Synth 8-690]). There also appears to be a second error - `q<= '0';` would be a type mismatch if q is an array type. '0' would represent an element type. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).